# WalletCard.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setDefaultAccount is not a function (REACT)

Tags: reactjs

No logro resolver el error que me aparece indicando que setDefaultAccount no es una función, ya que la tengo declarada previamente.
Aquí va mi código

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import React, {useState} from "react"

const WalletCard =() => {
const {errorMessage,setErrorMessage} = useState(null);
const {defaultAccount,setDefaultAccount} = useState(null);
const {userBalance,setUserBalance} = useState(null);
const {connButtonText,setConnButtonText} = useState ("Connect Wallet");


const conectWalletHandler = () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {

    window.ethereum.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"})

    .then(result => {
        accountChangedHandler (result [0]);
    }) 

  } else {
      setErrorMessage ("Install Metamask");
    }
}


const accountChangedHandler = (newAccount) =>{

    setDefaultAccount({newAccount});
    getUserBalance(newAccount);

}

const getUserBalance = (address) => {
    window.ethereum.request({method:"eth_getBalance",params:[address, "latest"]})
    .then(balance => {
        setUserBalance(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance))
    })
}


return (
    <div className="WalletCard">
        <h4>{"Conectá tu metamask usando window.ethereum methods"}</h4>
        <button onClick={conectWalletHandler}>{connButtonText}Connect Metamask Wallet</button>
        <div className="accountDisplay">
            <h3>Address:{defaultAccount}</h3>

        </div>
        <div className="balanceDisplay">
            <h3>Blance:{userBalance}</h3>
        </div>

        {errorMessage}

    </div>
);
}

export default WalletCard;
```

Como pueden ver, en `const {defaultAccount,setDefaultAccount} = useState(null);` dejo definida la funcion de setear la cuenta por defecto, pero después en consola me aparece el error de que no es una función. Seguramente es un error tonto, pero no me doy cuenta de cuál es.

Gracias por su ayuda de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Los `useState` no te devuelven objetos, te devuelven *arreglos*, por lo tanto debes cambiar la manera en que preparas tus estados; recíbelos con corchetes `[]` en lugar de llaves `{}`:

```
const [errorMessage,setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
const [defaultAccount,setDefaultAccount] = useState(null);
const [userBalance,setUserBalance] = useState(null);
const [connButtonText,setConnButtonText] = useState("Connect Wallet");
```

Comment: Gracias! Ya lo había podido solucionar, fué solo un error de lectura jajaja